# Is this incorrect use of useCallback and useEffect

Tags: react-hooks

I'm trying to build an upload files using react hooks, and I'm still a beginner at React, I have implemented upload files but I have some issues like when I upload a file called "A.png" and I try to upload the same file again the onUpload function not fired. till I upload another file like "B.png". I think this is happened because of incorrect use of useCallback and useEffect.
Here is my shot:

```
export const UploadAssets = (props) => {  
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<FileList>();

  const fileInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //some code...
  }, []);

  const onChooseFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileInput && fileInput.current) {
      props.options.onStart();
      fileInput.current.click();
    }
  }

  const onChangeFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileInput && fileInput.current && fileInput.current.files) {  
      props.options.onChooseFile(fileInput.current.files);     
      setFiles(fileInput.current.files);      
    }
  }

  const onUpload = useCallback(() => {
      if (!files) return false;
  
      let formData = new FormData();

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        formData.append(file.name, file);
      }
  
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('post', myUrl, true);
      xhr.send(formData);

      return true;
    }, [files],
  );

  useEffect(() => {  
    if (files) {
      onUpload();
    }
  }, [files])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onChooseFile}>
        Upload File
      </button>
      <input type="file" ref={fileInput} onChange={onChangeFile} hidden/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and as far as I know, it's not a good practice to call the onUpload function inside onChangeFile.

Comment: What is the reason for adding useCallback on onUpload ? When you upload the same file, value in your state remains the same and it skip the onUpload.

Comment: Even if I remove the useCallback I stay face the same problem.

Comment: When I remove useCallback from onUpload, onChangeFile function is not fired.

Answer (score 1):

> when I upload a file called "A.png" and I try to upload the same file again the onUpload function not fired. till I upload another file like "B.png".

This is because you are only calling `onUpload` when the `files` state changes:

```js
  useEffect(() => {  
    if (files) {
      onUpload();
    }
  }, [files])
```

`useEffect` in this case will only call the function passed to it when `files` changes, so if you reselect the same file the `<input type="file" />` will not trigger an `onchange` event and your `onChangeFile` handler which updates the `files` state will not be called.

Do you even really need to store `files` in state? I would suggest no, you do not need the extra re-renders when a user selects a new file.

I would try changing it to something like this:

```js
export const UploadAssets = (props) => {  
  const fileInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const onChooseFile = useCallback(() => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileInput.current) {
      props.options.onStart();
      fileInput.current.click();
    }
  }, [props.options.onStart, fileInput])

  const onUpload = useMemo(() => {
    return files => {
      if (!files) return false;
  
      let formData = new FormData();

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        formData.append(file.name, file);
      }
  
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('post', myUrl, true);
      xhr.send(formData);

      return true;
    }
  }, [])

  const onChangeFile = useCallback(() => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileInput.current && fileInput.current.files) {
      props.options.onChooseFile(fileInput.current.files);
      onUpload(fileInput.current.files);   
    }
  }, [props.options.onChooseFile, fileInput, onUpload])

  useEffect(() => {
    //some code...
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onChooseFile}>
        Upload File
      </button>
      <input type="file" ref={fileInput} onChange={onChangeFile} hidden/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- This calls `useCallback` on the buttons click event handler to preserve the referential integrity of the handler across re-renders (although now that I removed `useState` you probably don't need this optimization).
- This removes `useState` because it did not seem necessary. You are passing the selected files to the prop callbacks anyway.
- Rolls the `onUpdate` call inside of `onChangeFile` and preserves the reference across re-renders by wrapping it inside of `useMemo`.
- Moves the hook calls after the variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the input field first before firing the `onChange` function

```
function clearInput(e){
     e.target.value = ''
}

<input type="file" ref={fileInput} onChange={onChangeFile} onClick={clearInput} hidden/>
```